# how to close window instead of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Somehow I cannot access & close a JFrame with.dispose(), and it gives me a nullPointerException. Neither do I want to do a System.exit(0). How do I access the JFrame directly, is there a workaround to close the JFrame?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                frame = new ScannerUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);                         
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           

        }
    });
```

}

... (further down, and I cannot access the JFrame already, gives me a nullpointerexception)

```
                    btnBack.setBounds(400, 270, 80, 40);
                    panel.add(btnBack);
                    btnBack.setText ("BACK");       
                    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                            //ScannerUI.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE();
                            //frame.dispose();
                            //this.dispose();
                            //frame.setVisible(false);
                            //System.out.println ("dsakjf;dsalkhfsa;lklf");

                            //System.exit(0);
                            //JFrame test = ScannerUI.frame;
                            //test.dispose();
                            //  p = false;
                            System.out.println ("asdfasfas");

                            System.exit(frame.dispose());
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Why assume that "there is no way to access the JFrame directly"? Probably the best solution is to write your code so that it is fully functional. For instance give the class that holds the JFrame a public method that other classes can call to change the behavior of its contained components, such as closing the JFrame. For better help, show pertinent code. Then maybe we can help you with specific answers. Also, maybe a better solution is not to open and close windows, but til we see your code, we can only guess.

Comment: You are wanting to do this just from code, not from UI, correct?

Comment: Err, the window and the JFrame are the same thing. Post code if you want help. And post the full stack trace of the exception. Don't assume something is impossible or has to be worked around just because your code has a bug.

Comment: yes, i wish to do it from code. Please see edit.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't try to close the frame. And you haven't posted the exception stack trace.

Comment: Try assuming that we don't know what you're doing: your code fragment has nothing in it to tell us where "the JFrame" is, no indication of where your null pointer error occurs, and you don't tell us, overall, what you're trying to do.  We should not have to drag information out of you bit by bit (so to speak); describe your problem as though we are helpful people who do not know what you're up to.

Comment: I have a nullpointerexception, which is why i am trying to do a workaround. or perhaps I can access the JFrame in another way, say a constructor?

Comment: Again, we have no idea what your problem is based on the little bits of information you've given us so far. To avoid the mutual frustration of our having to keep requesting little pieces of information from you, please give us a bigger more complete picture of your problem. Else we cannot help you.

Comment: And go [edit]ing the Question to improve it, don't add new info here in comments. See [ask] and http://sscce.org

Comment: Sorry if it feels like you're being gunned down with criticism, but it's helpful if your code is compilable.

Comment: I appreciate all the help here. my goal is to access the JFrame within the actionListener, afterwhich I believe all will be fine.

Comment: Post an SSCCE (see http://sscce.org). And post the exception stack trace. It's been the 3rd time you're being asked to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the SwingUtilities method, getWindowAncestor, to help you get the window that holds the button and then call dispose on it:

```
btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
       AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
       Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(button);
       window.dispose();
    }
});
```

Another option is to get the enclosing object of the current class (if it is the JFrame). You can get this from within your anonymous inner class by using the class name, a period, followed by this, or for you: `ScannerUI.this`:

```
btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
       ScannerUI.this.dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, for generic code that doesn't depend on instance variables. I like the first approach because then you can create a generic Action that can be used by any class. @user2945412, SwingUtilities has other interesting methods to look at.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) and use the `ExitAction`. This is a more generic solution that will simulate a user clicking the "X" on the window. In this case any WindowsListeners you have added to the frame will be invoked first before the window is closed.

May not be applicable in this case, but just something to think about.